# How to change UID and Permissions on Red hat 7?

Tags: linux

I have a redhat7 server with detail below

**User :** sftp1

**UID :** 441

**New UID :** 560

I need to **change UID from 441 to 560** and need to **update existing permissions to new UID**.

Does anyone know the command to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To change the user id use this command:

```
usermod -u 560 sftp1
```

> -u, --uid UID
>       The new numerical value of the user's ID.

[usermod man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)

you need to be logged in with a different user to execute that command.

You can utilized `find` to identify and change the ownership of files belonging to that user like this:

```
find / -uid 441 -exec chown -h 560 {} +
```

You might want to use a path more specific than `/` as:

> The user's mailbox, and any files which the user owns and which are located in the user's home directory will have the file user ID changed automatically.

[usermod man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)